Expo development build not using app.json credentials: Solved by ignoring iOS and Android folders
I recently encountered an issue where my Expo app wasn’t reading the credentials and configurations from app.json when building in development mode. After some investigation, I realized that Expo was prioritizing the native iOS and Android folders (which had been initialized for previous builds) over the app.json settings.
When I ran npx expo run:android or npx expo run:ios, my app didn’t use the credentials from app.json, and Firebase configurations, among other settings, were not being applied.
The solution that worked for me was to add the ios/ and android/ folders to .gitignore. This forces Expo to fall back on the app.json configuration, and my app started using the correct credentials for both platforms.
Here’s how I added them to .gitignore:
/ios
/android

After doing this, my development build respected the app.json settings and correctly applied the Firebase credentials and other configurations.
